# Python - Module Not Found error when trying to run my test

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, pycharm

I am getting 'Module Not Found' error when trying to run my 'MaintainsRolesTest' script under 'TestExecutionScripts'.

I have been trying to investigate this for the past 2 days without any success. I have attached my pycharm project structure and my sys.path results from both Pycharm and Python IDLE. I am a total beginner to python with selenium

[Pycharm Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IvetJ.jpg)

[Syspath results - Running directly in IDLE - Python](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FyVyN.jpg)

[Syspath results-Running in Pycharm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pOD2r.jpg)

```
    from AmortizationModel.PageObjects import HomePage
    from AmortizationModel.PageObjects import LoginPage
    from AmortizationModel.PageObjects import MaintainRoles
    from selenium import webdriver
```

I have looked at my environment variables and below is the path present based on my investigation.

Can someone please guide me in the right direction in order for me to investigate it further and resolve the issue?

Comment: Did you try to modify your import like this? from WebAutomation.AmortizationModel.PageObjects import MaintainRoles

Comment: Please read why [a screenshot of code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code and properly format it instead.

Comment: @Giordano - Yes I tried that. WebAutomation doesn't even show up in the code autocomplete.

Comment: doesn't matter, try to execute it anyway and let me know please

Comment: @Giordano - Below is the error I got after execution: C:\Users\mahalr\PycharmProjects\WebAutomation\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/mahalr/PycharmProjects/WebAutomation/TestExecutionScripts/HomePage/MaintainRolesTest.py Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:/Users/mahalr/PycharmProjects/WebAutomation/TestExecutionScripts/HomePage/MaintainRolesTest.py", line 1, in <module> from WebAutomation.AmortizationModel.PageObjects import HomePage ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'WebAutomation' Process finished with exit code 1 –